# Finding IBM SAS 15k HDD specifications

Tags: ibm, hard-drive

We've ordered set of 15k 300G IBM HDDs to build RAID. 
On a question about which HDD model we will have, hw vendor provided following data:
P/N 43X0802 300Gb 15K HS SAS HDD

This label tell me nothing about advanced technical characteristics of a drive.
I've tried to search IBM website looking for technical specification using P/N but without luck. That's just weird, or possibly I'm searching wrong place.
Probably under this label there is some concrete model of Seagate drive, most of our old IBM 15K SAS drives are Seagate Cheetah models, but they also vary in model numbers and performance as well.

Maybe someone had such experience of decrypting IBM HDD labels.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

IBM will have left their published specification open enough to allow them to supply their same part number with different disks from different suppliers as required, so there's no certainty that you'll get a specific make/model ordered under that part number. What is it you're actually trying to achieve here?

Comment: We had problems with previous delivery, so now I'm trying to avoid such pitfalls. It was bulk of IBM drives consist of 4x 15k SAS drives - they all had same FRU but (what smartctl showed) different models - 3x3xST3300655SS(with different firmware) and 1xVPBA300C3ETS11 N. Month before we did install of a RAID on identical server configuration and all IBM drives had same ST3300656SS model. RAID performance of last configuration was significantly worse than configuration with same drive models.

Comment: According to seagate specifications:

ST3300655SS is model of 2007 with Sustainable disc transfer rate*:
Minimum 73 Mbytes/sec, Maximum 125 Mbytes/sec

ST3300656SS is model of 2008 Sustainable disk transfer rate*:
Minimum 112 Mbytes/sec (typical), Maximum 171 Mbytes/sec (typical) 

Quite big difference assuming we did request of a new 15k drives.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to get the firmware level via the sticker on the drives, but you can get the Model number off the sticker on the drives themselves, which should tell you the manufacturer/model of the drive.  For example, Model # ST3146855SS is a Seagate Cheetah.